# Windows 10 cursor dissapeared after update

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse-cursor

So, I had Windows 10 for about an year and everything was ok, until 2 days ago. 
When I went to my laptop (Asus F550JX if it helps) I found out that my cursor was missing from the computer.
I checked my mouse (HP wired mouse X1200) and when I logged in the red light from the sensor was on, meaning that it got power, but it didn't work, then 15-20 seconds later it turned off, and it happens every time I plug it in the laptop. The touchpad wasn't working either.
I tried to update drivers with device manager, didn't work, went to the devices tab in windows 10 settings panel and it detected the mouse, still the same. I disabled "Hide pointer while typing" and when I found out it didn't work I went here to ask this question.
So, here I am, did anyone go through this to help me?

Comment: Does your touchpad work if you disconnect your mouse?

Comment: @freginold unfortunately no

Comment: So just to confirm: if you plug your mouse in, it will work for 15-20 seconds then stop working, and if you unplug it and plug it back in, the same thing will happen again?

Comment: @freginold no, it just lights up and doesn't work, I'll edit it to clear confusion

Comment: No chance the mouse and/or trackpad are disabled in Device Manager, is there?

Comment: @freginold I didn't disable anything, last time I disabled something, I re-enabled it anyway

Comment: Go search for it starting at your desk. Just read the title, though.

Answer (score 0):

When the mouse cursor disappears, it means Windows did not detect any mouse. This means, windows did not detect your touchpad, nor did it detected the phyisical mouse. Given that the red light goes off confirms this.

The reason why this is not working can be due to several things:

1. The driver of the mouse is corrupted or not installed
2. The driver of the chipset is corrupted or not installed (most likely the case) which means that any USB device is not working.
3. The mouse is connected to a USB hub that is unable to get enough power from the port to sustain all devices.
4. The USB port itself is broken and its a coincidence that it happened nearly at the same time of the update.
5. The mouse itself is broken (test it using another computer)

My advice is to update all drivers to the latest version, including those of the chipset which is used for the USB ports. Also try plugging in the mouse to a different USB port, which will make the mouse to be reinstalled. Also unplug any other device you are not using.

Comment: Tried in another computer, works, tried in another usb port on the laptop, it doesn't, it isn't in a USB hub, inserted the disk that came with the laptop, saw it saying that just the LAN drivers are missing

Comment: Also, check if you can enable/disable the trackpad by using either a button or fn+Fx key. Every laptop has this key somewhere. For some, it is an obscured instruction, such as holding a dot on the trackpad itself, others have a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: yes, it's fn+f9, tried it, unfortunetely still doesn't work, gonna try to see if this problem persists on an ubuntu live usb later